# Unable to connect woocommerce rest api with angular 4

Tags: wordpress, angular, api, ionic-framework, woocommerce

I am trying to connect my woocommerce rest api with angular 4 to fetch product list in my ionic 3 project but every time url throw 404 not found errror i am not able to understand what i am doing wrong

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  WooCommerce: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.WooCommerce = WC({
      url: "http://localhost:8100/wordpress/wp-json/",
      consumerKey: "ck_4d99b09e85e45a11282fe2150945fc2090eea0f0",
      consumerSecret: "cs_3acf2c3eeb334ab84309e890a5070f8509de9201"
    });

    this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then( (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing Santosh you should always avoid using your private keys while asking questions , just mention like i did.

i am using this api currently in my app and faced the same issue, try using the exact same url which you use to open the site locally.
i think changing your url to just "http://localhost:8100/wordpress/" should work

```
this.WooCommerce = WC({
  url: "http://localhost:8100/wordpress/",
  consumerKey: "your consumer key",
  consumerSecret: "your consumer secret"
});
```

or else in my case i just passed version along it and it worked, you can check by passing both wpApi and version and hopefully that works

```
this.WooCommerce = WC({
  url: "http://localhost:8100/wordpress/",
  consumerKey: "your consumer key",
  consumerSecret: "your consumer secret",
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'v3'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue but now  i got the solution.
Just add these lines in .htaccess file that is in your woocommerce folder.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

And set the url in home.ts like
    url: "http://localhost:8100/wordpress/",

instead of
    url: "http://localhost:8100/wordpress/wp-json/",